# nodemanager is connected to resourcemanager, but datanode is not connected to namenode

Tags: java, hadoop

I install hadoop 2.5.1 over CentOS 7.0.

(1) When I run the app over hadoop, I'm doubtful below message path "/tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1424775783787_0001/files" is caused due to compatibility.
    If it's compatiblity issue, then How could I patch this??

> 15/02/24 20:27:41 ERROR streaming.StreamJob: Error Launching job : 
>     File /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/hadoop/.staging/job_1424775783787_0001/files/Formatter.sh could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 0 datanode(s) running and no node(s) are excluded in this operation.

(2) The port master:9000 is listen, however the datanode is not connected to master,
but the nodemanager is alive.
so I can check the active datanodes from 8088 port
however it's not check in 50070 port

The configuration is like below.

host file

```
    XXX.XXX.XXX.65 mccb-com65 #server
    XXX.XXX.XXX.66 mccb-com66  #client01
    XXX.XXX.XXX.67 mccb-com67  #client02
    127.0.1.1      mccb-com65 (mccb-com66, mccb-com67 per computer setting)
    127.0.0.1      localhost
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://XXX.XXX.XXX.65:9000</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<configuration>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
   <value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs/namenode</value>
   <description>the path which save the file system image </description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:///home/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs/datanode</value>
   <description>the path which the datanode save the block</description>
</property>
<property>
   <name>dfs.http.address</name>
   <value>0.0.0.0:50070</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50075</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.ipc.address</name>
    <value>0.0.0.0:50020</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>3</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
       <value>-Xmx400m</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.address</name>
       <value>0.0.0.0:10020</value>
    </property>
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.jobhistory.webapp.address</name>
       <value>0.0.0.0:19888</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.system.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs/mapred/system</value>
       <final>true</final>       
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapred.local.dir</name>
        <value>/home/hadoop/hdfs/hdfs/mapred/local</value>
        <final>true</final>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
      <value>XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8031</value>
   </property>
   <property> 
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
      <value>XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8030</value>
   </property>
   <property> 
       <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
       <value>XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8032</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>yarn.resoucemanager.webapp.address </name>
       <value>XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8088</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.webapp.address  </name>
       <value>0.0.0.0:8042</value>
    </property>
  </configuration>
```

> [root@mccb-com65 ~]# netstat -antlp
>
> Active Internet connections (servers and established) 
>     Proto Recv-Q
>       Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
>       PID/Program name    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25
>       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2868/master         tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>       1746/xrdp           tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8030
>       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10858/java          tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8031     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>       10858/java          tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8032
>       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10858/java          tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8033            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>       10858/java          tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50885
>       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2282/rpc.statd      tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.65:9000     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>       10470/java          tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50090
>       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10684/java          tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>       1753/rpcbind        tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50070
>       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      10470/java          tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>       1745/xrdp-sesman    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22
>       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1761/sshd           tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>       3278/cupsd          tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5911
>       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3053/Xvnc           tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8088            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
>       10858/java          tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8031
>       XXX.XXX.XXX.67:44914    ESTABLISHED 10858/java          tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.65:42505    XXX.XXX.XXX.65:9000     TIME_WAIT   -
>   tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5911          127.0.0.1:50271
>       ESTABLISHED 3053/Xvnc           tcp        0      0
>       XXX.XXX.XXX.65:3389     XXX.XXX.XXX.96:52951    ESTABLISHED 1746/xrdp           tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:50271
>       127.0.0.1:5911          ESTABLISHED 1746/xrdp           tcp        0      0 XXX.XXX.XXX.65:8031     XXX.XXX.XXX.66:46816    ESTABLISHED
>       10858/java          tcp6       0      0 :::44331                :::*
>       LISTEN      2282/rpc.statd      tcp6       0      0 :::111
>       :::*                    LISTEN      1753/rpcbind        tcp6       0
>       0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
>       1761/sshd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps should fix the issue. **However, you may lose data.**

- Stop Hadoop :

  - sbin/stop-dfs.sh
  - sbin/stop.yarn.sh
- Delete NameNode & DataNode:

  - hdfs dfs -rm -r /hdfs/namenode
  - hdfs dfs -rm -r /hdfs/datanodenode
- Format NameNode

  - hdfs namenode -format
- Start NameNode, Datanodes & YARN

  - sbin/start-dfs.sh
  - sbin/start-yarn.sh

Comment: @EunhuiKim Happy it worked. It would be great if you could accept the answer as the  solution to your problem. It will help many others looking for solution to the exact same problem.

 http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I do, it's my first question in stackoverflow, so I'm unfamiliar with stackoverflow even writing and selecting, chcking.... ^^

Comment: When deleting the datanode and namenode, I just use "rm -rf namenode"  commend as root user because hdfs dfs command requests the namenode to be active to open the port 9000. ^^